# Filter Commonsware Cwac Image Android

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am wondering does anyone know how is the best way to implement filters using commonsware-cwac.

I want to update the camera preview each time the user chooses a different filter

Andrew

Comment: Why do you think the cwac components has to do something with the filters?

Comment: No not filter, the camera host preview is a bitmap and want to update the bitmap that has a filter on it

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use filters, do not use the CWAC-Camera library. You are trying to write a real camera app, and that is not what my library is for. Quoting [the `README`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#library-objectives):

> The targeted use case is an app that might otherwise have relied upon ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, but needs greater reliablilty and somewhat greater control (e.g., capture images directly to internal storage).
>
> If you are trying to write "a camera app" — an app whose primary job is to take pictures — this library may be unsuitable for you.

Please use the `Camera2` (Android 5.0+) and `Camera` (Android 4.4 and older) APIs directly.